# Not able to disable Azure AD Connect

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for a solution to my problem and I am not able to find it. I've tried everything online.

I'm trying to disable our on premise AD connect, I ran it as a test but it turns out our environment is not setup correctly for this to work and requires some restructuring.

I've followed the standard instructions of

`Connect-MsolService` and `Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false`

Connect works fine but when I try to run the disable command it returns back the error `Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled : You cannot turn off Active Directory synchronization.`

I've been told it could take a while but I had enabled it last week and most resources I've found say "24 - 72 hours".

The command `(Get-MSOLCompanyInformation).DirectorySynchronizationStatus` shows `Enabled` and not syncing.

Can anyone assist me with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: the Command which you have used no problem in that. Please be wait for 72hr . it takes some time to reflect the change.... : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/turn-off-directory-synchronization?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Please refer this as well it may help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/150143/disable-ad-connect.html

Comment: Ya, I forgot to mention. I've waited far more than 72 hours. It's been about 170 hours (7 days) since I enabled it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that may be your tenant size is large is taking longer than expected. If not so you can reach out to MS Support they can help you to find where the exact issue .

Comment: Azure support : https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview

Answer (score 0):

You try to enable (or disable) Directory synchronization in Office 365, and you are greeted by the following error message.

```
PS C:\> Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false
 
Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled : You cannot turn off Active Directory synchronization.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled], MicrosoftOnlineException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.DirSyncStatusChangeNotAllowedException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetDirSyncEnabled
```

The `DirSyncStatusChangeNotAllowedException` error in particular means that you have changed the status recently, and the service is simply preventing you from changing it back too soon

> Note : The error message detailed is different and will occur even if the
> DirSync status has been updated. It’s a simple block on Microsoft’s
> side to prevent you from changing the status too often

check now or wait for atleast 12 hours to 72hr to reflect.

```
MSOLCompanyInformation | select DirectorySynchronizationStatus
```

NO FIX: Unfortunately, there is no way around this error. It simply means that your directory is still doing a full initial synch with Azure AD. This error message will clear once the initial sync is complete. The time will vary depending on the size of your on-premises AD but should take no longer than 72 hours for very large environments.

Reference : https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1797/you-cannot-turn-off-active-directory-synchronization

Note : If still problem is not getting solved would suggest you to reach out to [MS Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). They can able to track down where the exact. issue